# How to center on HTML5?

Tags: html, center, centering

On my website, I was previously displaying 4 plan cards. I'm looking on displaying only 3 cards, so I commented one of them. As result, they are not centered. How can I center them?

Here's how it's being currently displayed:

[image: Plans Current Display]

Here's the code:

```html
<!-- Row fuid-->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Item table -->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item_table">
      <div class="head_table">
        <h1>FREE</h1>
        <h2>£ 0.00 <span>/ Mo</span></h2>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="color">2 GB HDD</li>
        <li>25GB Bandwidth</li>
        <li class="color">1 E-mail Account</li>
        <li>1 Sub Domains</li>
        <li class="color">cPanel/Site Creator</li>
        <li>1 FTP Account</li>
        <li class="color">1 Cron Job</li>
        <li>1 Addon Domain</li>
        <li class="color">1 Parked Domain</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="signup.html" class="button">Order Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Item table -->

  <!-- Item table -->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item_table">
      <div class="head_table">
        <h1>PREMIUM</h1>
        <h2>£ 0.99 <span>/ Mo</span></h2>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="color">30 GB HDD</li>
        <li>1000GB Bandwidth</li>
        <li class="color">1024MB RAM</li>
        <li>2 Dedicated IP Addresses</li>
        <li class="color">cPanel/WHM Included</li>
        <li>Open VZ Included</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="signup.html" class="button">Order Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Item table -->

  <!-- Item table -->
  <!--<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="item_table">
            <div class="head_table">
                <h1>V.I.P</h1>
                <h2>£ 2.00  <span>/ Mo</span></h2>
                <!--<h5>Or  $ 150.5 Yearly!</h5>
            </div>
            <ul>  
                <li class="color">30 GB HDD</li>
                <li>1000GB Bandwidth</li>
                <li class="color">1024MB RAM</li>
                <li>2 Dedicated IP Addresses</li>
                <li class="color">cPanel/WHM Included</li>
                <li>Open VZ Included</li>
            </ul> 
            <a href="www.clearhostsolutions.com/signup.html" class="button">Order Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>-->
  <!-- End Item table -->
```

Comment: Your example code seems like it's incomplete, there's no end div for the <div class=row>

Comment: People are giving HTML5/CSS answers but I think you're asking how to do this with the bootstrap classes. right?

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `<div align="center">stuff here</div>` and it will work fine just if you want the containing items to not center content on them say `<tag style="text-align:left;">...</tag>`

Another way is to inside your `CSS` file have the following code:

```
* { margin:0px auto; }
div.container { width:1000px; border:1px solid black; }
```

The `*` applies to the entire page and sets up the page to be centered.
You then need some other tag like `div` with a set width to take advantage of the property.

In your `HTML` file:

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's two answers...

CSS has `text-align: center` and with Bootstrap's 12 column layout, you need to give each column 4 each  I used the `col-sm-4` since JSFiddle's window is small.

Here's my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/N7mvN/ *make sure to pull the display window open wider to see it*

Here's the HTML:

```html
<!-- Row fuid-->
    <div>
        <div class="row" style="margin:0 auto">
            <!-- Item table -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="item_table" style="background-color:red">
                    <div class="head_table">
                        <h1>FREE</h1>
                        <h2>£ 0.00  <span>/ Mo</span></h2>
                    </div>
                    <ul>  
                        <li class="color">2 GB HDD</li>
                        <li>25GB Bandwidth</li>
                        <li class="color">1 E-mail Account</li>
                        <li>1 Sub Domains</li>
                        <li class="color">cPanel/Site Creator</li>
                        <li>1 FTP Account</li>
                        <li class="color">1 Cron Job</li>
                        <li>1 Addon Domain</li>
                        <li class="color">1 Parked Domain</li>
                    </ul> 
                    <a href="signup.html" class="button">Order Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item table -->

            <!-- Item table -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="item_table" style="background-color:green">
                    <div class="head_table">
                        <h1>PREMIUM</h1>
                        <h2>£ 0.99  <span>/ Mo</span></h2>
                    </div>
                    <ul>  
                        <li class="color">30 GB HDD</li>
                        <li>1000GB Bandwidth</li>
                        <li class="color">1024MB RAM</li>
                        <li>2 Dedicated IP Addresses</li>
                        <li class="color">cPanel/WHM Included</li>
                        <li>Open VZ Included</li>
                    </ul> 
                    <a href="signup.html" class="button">Order Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item table -->

            <!-- Item table -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="item_table" style="background-color:blue">
                    <div class="head_table">
                        <h1>V.I.P</h1>
                        <h2>£ 2.00  <span>/ Mo</span></h2>
                        <h5>Or  $ 150.5 Yearly!</h5>
                    </div>
                    <ul>  
                        <li class="color">30 GB HDD</li>
                        <li>1000GB Bandwidth</li>
                        <li class="color">1024MB RAM</li>
                        <li>2 Dedicated IP Addresses</li>
                        <li class="color">cPanel/WHM Included</li>
                        <li>Open VZ Included</li>
                    </ul> 
                    <a href="www.clearhostsolutions.com/signup.html" class="button">Order Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item table -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

And some extra CSS:

```css
.item_table {
    margin:1.5em;
    padding:1em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hello this worked, quick question how would i get it back to the layout i had? ie the colour??

Comment: In the html I added some style to the list items. Remove the parts that say background-color

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them all in a div with the style attribute set to `margin: 0px auto; width: 1000px;` where 1000px is the width of the contained elements. ie. will need to be changed considering I don't know the widths of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="third inline"><!-- content --></div>
<div class="third inline"><!-- content --></div>
<div class="third inline"><!-- content --></div>

</div>
```

css

```
.third{
width:30%;
margin:0;}

.inline{
display:inline-block;}

.container{
width:50%;/*whatever*/
margin:0 auto;}
```